# PhpStorm: Remove whitespaces till next non-whitespace

Tags: phpstorm

I recently switched tot PhpStorm and miss a hotkey to remove whitespaces till next non-whitespace.

Example (pipe beeing the cursor):

```
Lorem[ ]Ipsum[ ]|[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]dolo[ ]agit[ ]
```

Pressing the hotkey (e.g. Ctrl+T in Nuspheres PhpEd), the result should be

```
Lorem[ ]Ipsum[ ]|dolo[ ]agit[ ]
```

Is there a setting or plugin for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if such a function exists in PhpStorm (I couldn't find one). You can use the commands `Delete to Line End` followed by `Delete to Word End`.

The command `Delete to Line End` removes everything (whitespaces or not) from the caret until (and including) the end of line.
You can find it in the `Preferences` dialog box, on the `Keymap` page and assign a hotkey to it; it doesn't come with any hotkey attached, at least on OSX.

The command `Delete to Word End` removes everything (whitespaces or not) from the caret until the next word boundary. In your case, the caret should be before the four whitespaces in front of `dolo` and it should do what you need.
On OSX this command can be triggered by the <kbd>Alt-Delete</kbd> hotkey, I think on Windows the hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl-Delete</kbd>. Please use the `Preferences` dialog box to check if this is true; I'm making assumptions now based on my knowledge of Windows and OSX but I didn't use PhpStorm on Windows in the last 4 years and I may be wrong.

You can record a macro (menu -> `Edit` -> `Macros` -> `Start Macro Recording`) and then assign a hotkey to it (in `Preferences` -> `Keymap`) but it's probably not the best option because both commands delete both whitespaces and non-whitespaces characters.

The best way to use them, in my oppinion, is standalone, depending on the situation at hand. For example, if `Ipsum` and `dolo` are on the same line then only the second command (`Delete to Word End`) must be used. The first one deletes more than you need.

Comment: ctrl+delete (windows 7) was exactly the solution I was looking for - thank you!